# How to install libffi-dev and libssl-dev on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, paramiko, libffi

I am trying to run a piece of code using `paramiko`, but I get the error message `ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends`. Both `paramiko` and `cryptography` are already installed.

As far as I can read on various forums, I need to install `libffi-dev` (and maybe also `libssl-dev`). However, all solutions I can find are either for Ubuntu or Mac OS. How do I install them on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by running

```
pip install cryptography --force-reinstall
```

and

```
pip install paramiko --force-reinstall
```

Comment: I get: `no such option: --forcereinstall`